# PHP - Autoloader doesn't work when registering it EDIT

Tags: php, autoload, autoloader, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I am trying to autoload a class, but my autoloader doesn't seem to register properly.

`Folder/File structure`:

- zest.php
- east

  - a.thing.php

`**zest.php**`:

```
<?php
    $aThing = new a;
    $aThing->test();

    function my_autoloader($class) {
        include 'aest/' . $class . '.thing.php';
    }

    spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
?>
```

`**a.thing.php**`:

```
<?php
class a {
    public function test() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

I pulled this example straight from php.net, what is wrong with it?

**The autoloader function doesn't get called at all.**

**Not even when it is an anoymous function:**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    echo 'calling '.$class;
    include 'aest/'.$class . '.test.php';
});
```

Comment: It should work. Do you get any errors? Try to debug it, are you at the proper path? Do a `var_dump(getcwd());` in your autoload..

Comment: @lolka_bolka `Class '<NAME>' not found...` is the error. `var_dump(getcwd());`, doesn't do anything, meaning that the register isn't working, but I am unable to find out why; not even an anonymous function registers...

Comment: I think you have a typo in `include 'aest/' . $class . '.thing.php';` it has to be `include 'east/' . $class . '.thing.php';`

Comment: @MAZux I don't see the difference between those two lines, but I copied it anyway. But I think the auto loader doesn't even get called to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ughh... `spl_autoload_register('AutoLoader')` has to be called before any attempt to instantiate a class that has to be autoloaded is made.